# Turn off autocomplete in chrome (completely)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, redux-form

Having an issue with autocomplete in chrome.

Stack: 
React,
Redux-forms

[autofill behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49yqv.png)

I turned it off by inserting random values to "autocomplete" input props and it works.
But i still get suggests which look like this:

As far as I have been able to find out, this behavior is caused by input`s "name" attribute that Field component of redux-form uses. Chrome seems to memorize values by inputs name.

Does anyone know how to avoid this autofill behavior without using random field names ?

Comment: I think you can't and should not, except if it is something like credit card number.

Comment: @CoderCharmander i want to use my own autocomplete and this is really irritating :(

Comment: try using `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: @Reactgular since 2017 chrome ignores autocomplete="off"

Comment: I found a solution: `autocomplete="false"` on input, or `autocomplete="off"` on form. I did not test it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @CodeCharmander tried it. still get that kind of suggests. It`s not even common browser autocomplete, it`s memorized values by browser.

Comment: @ CodeCharmander btw you could input any unsupported value in "autocomplete" prop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue kinda resolved. 
Suggests were showed cause i set an input's name = "fullname". 
This behavior can be avoided by setting name with something more abstract, like "customerFN". 
To turn off autocomplete you can set autcomplete="nope" or anything not supported.
"off" and "false" don't work anymore.